# jodd exmple error: Please provide ConnectionProvider implementation

Tags: jodd

i see the [Jodd in 30 minutes](http://joddframework.org/) and download the example.

but when i run the project, tomcat console

```
806 [ERROR] j.j.c.DefaultAppCore.start:278 - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Please provide ConnectionProvider implementation.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Please provide ConnectionProvider implementation.
    at jodd.joy.core.DefaultAppCore.createConnectionProvider(DefaultAppCore.java:612)
    at jodd.joy.core.DefaultAppCore.startDb(DefaultAppCore.java:562)
    at jodd.joy.core.DefaultAppCore.start(DefaultAppCore.java:272)
    at jodd.joy.core.DefaultWebApplication.initWebApplication(DefaultWebApplication.java:57)
    at jodd.madvoc.Madvoc.start(Madvoc.java:205)
    at jodd.madvoc.Madvoc.startNewWebApplication(Madvoc.java:180)
    at jodd.madvoc.MadvocContextListener.contextInitialized(MadvocContextListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
```

i use `eclipse` `maven` `mysql`

i import mysql jdbc and jodd db.

i dont know what is missing or where my mistake？

my pom.xml :

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jodd/jodd-joy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodd-joy</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jodd/jodd-bean -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodd-bean</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jodd/jodd-http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodd-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use Jodd **3.7.0**.

For some reason, our implementation was of provider was not bundled with 3.7.1. It will be returned in next version.

Or just take the code from [here](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/1953aa59446d3387bbf103cd011d59a20305fc40/jodd-db/src/test/java/jodd/db/pool/CoreConnectionPool.java)